# Add a tab to the Excel ribbon

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the code as below which i have adapted from the Net and it runs but does not add the button to the ribbon.  I am using Excel 2016 Professional Plus and i wondered if this is only possible using 365 and not 2016 or my code is wrong.  Any advice will be gratefully received.

Many thanks

regards

Spike

```
Sub CustomRibbon()
Dim hFile As Long
Dim path As String
Dim fileName As String
Dim ribbonXml As String
Dim user As String 

    hFile = FreeFile 
    user = Environ("Username")
    path = "C:\Users\" & user & "\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\" 
    fileName = "Excel.officeUI"  
    
    ribbonXml = "<mso:customUI onLoad=""RibbonOnLoad"" xmlns:mso=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui"">" & vbNewLine 
    
    ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "  <mso:ribbon>" & vbNewLine
    ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "    <mso:qat/>" & vbNewLine
    ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "    <mso:tabs>" & vbNewLine
    
    ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "      <mso:tab id=""CustomTab"" label=""SP"" insertBeforeQ=""mso:TabInsert"">" & vbNewLine
    ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "        <mso:group id=""GroupSP"" label=""SP"" autoScale=""true"">" & vbNewLine
    ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "          <mso:button id=""Report"" label=""Testing"" & vbNewLine"
    ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "imageMso=""ShapeDownArrow""      onAction=""Mac_1_run""/>" & vbNewLine
    
    ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "        </mso:group>" & vbNewLine
    ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "      </mso:tab>" & vbNewLine
    ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "    </mso:tabs>" & vbNewLine
    ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "  </mso:ribbon>" & vbNewLine
    ribbonXml = ribbonXml + "</mso:customUI>"
    
    Open path & fileName For Output Access Write As hFile
    Print #hFile, ribbonXml
    Close hFile

End sub
```

Answer (score 1):

### Add a Tab to the Ribbon

- Note that this will mess up whatever you have previously manually customized including the `Quick Access Toolbar`. Make a backup of your `Excel.officeUI` file before using this code.

**A Quick Fix**

```vb
Sub CustomRibbon()

    Const OfficePath As String = "\Microsoft\Office\"
    Const FileName As String = "Excel.officeUI"
    
    Dim LocalPath As String: LocalPath = Environ("LOCALAPPDATA")
    Dim FilePath As String: FilePath = LocalPath & OfficePath & FileName
    
    Dim ribbonXml As String
    
    ribbonXml = "<mso:customUI onLoad=""RibbonOnLoad"" xmlns:mso=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui"">" & vbLf
    ribbonXml = ribbonXml & "  <mso:ribbon>" & vbLf

' These are irrelevant at this moment.
' 'qat' is short for Quick Access Toolbar
'    ribbonXml = ribbonXml & "    <mso:qat>" & vbLf
'    ribbonXml = ribbonXml & "      <mso:sharedControls>" & vbLf
'    ribbonXml = ribbonXml & "      </mso:sharedControls> & vbLf
'    ribbonXml = ribbonXml & "    </mso:qat>" & vbLf
    
    ribbonXml = ribbonXml & "    <mso:tabs>" & vbLf
    ribbonXml = ribbonXml & "      <mso:tab id=""CustomTab"" label=""SP"" insertBeforeQ=""mso:TabInsert"">" & vbLf
    ribbonXml = ribbonXml & "        <mso:group id=""GroupSP"" label=""SP"" autoScale=""true"">" & vbLf
    ribbonXml = ribbonXml & "          <mso:button id=""Report"" label=""Testing"" imageMso=""ShapeDownArrow"" onAction=""Mac_1_run""/>" & vbLf
    ribbonXml = ribbonXml & "        </mso:group>" & vbLf
    ribbonXml = ribbonXml & "      </mso:tab>" & vbLf
    ribbonXml = ribbonXml & "    </mso:tabs>" & vbLf
    ribbonXml = ribbonXml & "  </mso:ribbon>" & vbLf
    ribbonXml = ribbonXml & "</mso:customUI>"
    
    Dim hFile As Long: hFile = FreeFile
    
    Open FilePath For Output Access Write As hFile
        Print #hFile, ribbonXml
    Close hFile

End Sub
```